# How to get the file size without locking the file

Tags: java, file, locking

I need to find a way to get the size of a file without locking it.

In my system, I have two Threads, the first uses Jsch to download a file to the linux file system while the second Thread get the file size. There is an interaction between the two Threads and Jsch throws an exception at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method).

Because Jsch is not my code, I can't synchronize the two Threads. My solution would be to not lock the file even if the value is not atomic.

```
fileAttributes = Files.readAttributes(tmpFile.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);

return fileAttributes.size();
```